# Where do http cookies come from, which are not set by "Set-Cookie" response headers?

Tags: http, cookies

I am trying to reconstruct/imitate a browser request from my spring boot backend.
I do a GET request to the server and store all the response headers with 'Set-Cookie', which are three in total.

When I delete my cookies and re-fire the request in browser though, ten cookies are added to my browser cookies instead of three. I went through the network traffic recording of Chrome and could not find any responses which set cookies despite the first one with three.

Where do the other seven cookies come from? How can I save those seven missing cookies to my backend in order to make a valid follow up request?

For reference: https://www.dhl.de/de/privatkunden/pakete-empfangen/verfolgen.html

[Cookies in browser request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4y8Z.png)

Thank you so much in advance, any resource means a lot to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript, document.cookies.

(I need more characters to hit the minumum for an answer)